# type String does not conform to protocol sequencetype

Tags: string, swift, sequence

Here is the code, I'm trying to make a simple calculator :

```
@IBAction func btnOperatorInput(sender: UIButton) {
    let op = ("+", "-", "*", "/")

    let nr1 = sender.currentTitle!
    var nr2 = ""
    if sender.currentTitle == nr1{

        display.text! = self.display.text! + nr1
        nrTaped = true

    } else if sender.currentTitle == String(op) {
        nrTaped = false

        nr2 = display.text!
        display.text! = String(String(nr1) + String(op))

    }

    for _ in op.0{

     self.calc.add(Int(nr1)!, secondNumber: Int(nr2)!)

    }



}
```

I get the error at the for loop. I don't know how to use the "+" (for example) from the String I created, when I press the + to add the numbers together!

Comment: I think the error says it best... you're can't iterate over a string, as it isn't a sequence. What exactly are you trying to do there? Also you should stop force unwrapping everything. Please learn how to [properly deal with optionals](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36360605/2976878).

Comment: I wanna use the "+" from the string, pass it to the button + and after, make the + opperation...

Comment: I'm confused as to why you are using a for loop there.

Comment: Swift Strings do not conform to SequenceType anymore, I believe since version 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is easily solved, you need to access the `String`'s `CharacterView`:

```
for _ in op.0.characters {

       self.calc.add(Int(nr1)!, secondNumber: Int(nr2)!)

}
```

Note: As another commenter has queried above, I'm not sure why you'd want to iterate over what will always be a single and predictable character but I guess this might just be example code.