# How to fix: Type 'String' does not conform to protocol 'SequenceType' in Swift

Tags: ios, string, swift, animation, label

I have a simple Label Text Animation in Swift. 
And I got the following error:

> Type 'String' does not conform to protocol 'SequenceType'

Below there are some of my codes:

`LabelTextAnimation.swift`:

```
import UIKit

func setTextWithTypeAnimation(inputText: String, interval: NSTimeInterval, label: UILabel) {

    label.text = ""

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(QOS_CLASS_USER_INTERACTIVE, 0)) {

        for character in inputText {  // 1

            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {

                label.text = label.text! + String(character)

            }

            NSThread.sleepForTimeInterval(interval)

        }

    }

}
```

`ViewController.swift`:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet var label: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        setTextWithTypeAnimation("This is very cool", interval: 0.13, label: label)

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}
```

`// 1` is the line with the error to the string: `inputText`.

Also, do you know a way for each character to have a different color?

I hope you could help me!
Thank you in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [type String does not conform to protocol sequencetype](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36479826/type-string-does-not-conform-to-protocol-sequencetype)

Comment: @Thilo, I think it's a bit more different.

Comment: See the example here under "Working with Characters" https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/StringsAndCharacters.html

Comment: @WilliamGP, Thank you! I will take a look.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Instead of doing `for character in inputText {}` you should do

`for character in inputText.characters {}`

Comment: note: 'characters' was obsoleted in Swift 5.0